# Spark ALS implicit exception

Tags: azure, pyspark

We use ALS on Azure Spark to build our recommender system.

For the computation power reason that we cannot output different recommendation list for each individual user. So we divide users into clusters and use ALS to output recommendation list for each individual cluster centroid.

Before clustering on users, we user standardscaler and normalizer on Spark to preprocess data in order to have better clustering result. However, this will cause the following exception when using ALS.trainImplicit

> 15/11/16 15:43:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 30.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 197) on executor localhost: java.lang.AssertionError (assertion failed: lapack.dppsv returned 4.) [duplicate 9]
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/rogeesjir_huasqngfda/woradofkapkspace/jigsusLaudfadfecher/scripts/RecommendationBackend/AzureSpark/src/collaborativeFiltering/spark_als.py", line 92, in 
>       main()
>     File "/home/rogeesjir_huasqngfda/rogeesjir_huasqngfda/jigsusLaudfadfecher/scripts/RecommendationBackend/AzureSpark/src/collaborativeFiltering/spark_als.py", line 39, in main
>       model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, numIter, alpha=0.01)
>     File "/home/jigsusLaudfadfecher/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.py", line 147, in trainImplicit
>   15/11/16 15:43:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 25.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 192) on executor localhost: java.lang.AssertionError (assertion failed: lapack.dppsv returned 4.) [duplicate 10]
>       iterations, lambda_, blocks, alpha, nonnegative, seed)
>     File "/home/jigsusLaudfadfecher/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 120, in callMLlibFunc
>       return callJavaFunc(sc, api, *args)
>     File "/home/jigsusLaudfadfecher/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 113, in callJavaFunc
>       return _java2py(sc, func(*args))
>     File "/home/jigsusLaudfadfecher/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in **call**
>     File "/home/jigsusLaudfadfecher/spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError15/11/16 15:43:11 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 16.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 183) on executor localhost: java.lang.AssertionError (assertion failed: lapack.dppsv returned 4.) [duplicate 11]
>
> : An error occurred while calling o39.trainImplicitALSModel.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 8 in stage 15.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 8.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 175, localhost): java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: lapack.dppsv returned 4.
>       at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$CholeskySolver.solve(ALS.scala:355)
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ml$recommendation$ALS$$computeFactors$1.apply(ALS.scala:1131)
>       at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ml$recommendation$ALS$$computeFactors$1.apply(ALS.scala:1092)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$mapValues$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:674)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$mapValues$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:674)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>       at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:249)
>       at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:172)
>       at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:79)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:242)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

When we remove the "regularization" component(i.e, not to do standardscaler and normalizer), everything works fine.
By the way, ALS.train() call for explicit rating also works fine even we regularize data before ALS model training.

Has anyone ever encounter this kind of problem?
We are still new so please help! Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your code and a sample data set?  The error reads potentially as though there is code running on workers that should not be.  Configuration details on your Spark cluster would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

For future readers :

> Several columns in the given dataset contain only zeros. In this case,
>   the data matrix is no full rank. Therefore the Gramian matrix is
>   singular and hence not invertible. The Cholesky decomposition will
>   fail in this case. This will also happen if standard deviation of more
>   than one columns is zero (even if the values are not zero). I think we
>   should catch this error in the code and exit with a warning message.
>   OR we can drop columns with zero variance, and continue with the
>   algorithm.

Taken from [comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11918?focusedCommentId=15127437&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15127437).

Just make sure most of the ratings are non-zero and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I get a similar error with `ALS.train()`:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: lapack.dpotrs returned 6.
...
```

Google brought me to an issue reported on the Spark JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11918 where the same error appears when doing Linear Regression with Weighted Least Squares (WLS). Apparently this error is thrown by LAPACK when you try to solve an ill-conditioned system of linear equations.

In my case increasing the `ALS.train()` parameter `lambda_` from the default value `0.01` to higher values `>= 0.02` seems to help, though I'm not sure if it will permanently fix my issue...